# PHP PDO No errors but not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have the following code to process my PHP form:

```
$result1 = $db->query("SELECT `name` FROM staff_fields WHERE `".$_SESSION['logged_business']."` = 'Yes'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$query = "UPDATE staff SET ";
foreach($result1 as $q){
    $query .= $q['name']."=:".$q['name'].", ";
}
$query = rtrim($query, ' ,')." WHERE id=:id";
$stmt = $db->prepare($query);
foreach($result1 as $col){
    $stmt->bindParam(':'.$col['name'], $_POST[$col['name']]);
}

$stmt->bindParam(':id', $_POST['id']);
if($stmt->execute())
    header('Location: staff.php?updated');
else
    echo "<center><h1>Error Updating Staff</h1></center>";
```

And the following code for the form it self.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff_fields WHERE ".$_SESSION['logged_business']."='Yes'");
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$stmt1 = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE id=:id");
$stmt1->bindParam(':id', $_GET['id']);
$stmt1->execute();
while($row1 = $stmt1->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
$table = "<form action='./edit_staff.php' method='post'>
            <table align='center'>";
    foreach($result as $res){
        $table .= 
                "
                    <tr>
                        <td>".$res['label']."</td>
                        <td>";

                        if($res['type'] == "text"){
                            $table .= "<input type='text' name='".$res['name']."' value='".$row1[0][$res['name']]."'/>";
                        }
                        if($res['type'] == "date"){
                            $table .= "<input type='date' name='".$res['name']."' value='";         
                            $date = new DateTime($row1[0][$res['name']]);
                            $table .= $date->format('Y-m-d')."'/>";
                        }
                        if($res['type'] == "yesno"){
                            $table .= "<select name='".$res['name']."' />";     
                            if($row1[0][$res['name']] == "Yes"){
                                    $table .= "<option value='Yes' selected>Yes</option>
                                                <option value='No'>No</option>";
                            }else{
                                $table .= "<option value='No' selected>No</option>
                                            <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>";
                            }   
                            $table .="</select>";
                        }

            $table .=  "</td>
                    </tr>
                ";
    }
    $table .="<tr><td><input type='hidden' number='id' value='".$row1[0]['id']."' /></td><td><input type='submit' name='btn' value='Add Staff' /></td></tr></table></form>";
    echo $table;
}
```

However despite debugging the code and investigating it isn't working.
It is the first part of the code that isn't working (form submission). 
I tried using debug params on the update statement but this is what I get:

```
SQL: [642] UPDATE staff SET first_name1459057776924=:first_name1459057776924, last_name1459057788088=:last_name1459057788088, job_title1459057796608=:job_title1459057796608, proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910=:proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910, date_of_birth1459057814082=:date_of_birth1459057814082, start_date1459057824504=:start_date1459057824504, signed_contract_in_place1459057835607=:signed_contract_in_place1459057835607, references_received1459057869650=:references_received1459057869650, payroll_informa Params: 11 Key: Name: [24] :first_name1459057776924 paramno=-1 name=[24] ":first_name1459057776924" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [23] :last_name1459057788088 paramno=-1 name=[23] ":last_name1459057788088" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [23] :job_title1459057796608 paramno=-1 name=[23] ":job_title1459057796608" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [34] :proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910 paramno=-1 name=[34] ":proof_of_age_on_file1459057805910" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [27] :date_of_birth1459057814082 paramno=-1 name=[27] ":date_of_birth1459057814082" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [24] :start_date1459057824504 paramno=-1 name=[24] ":start_date1459057824504" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [38] :signed_contract_in_place1459057835607 paramno=-1 name=[38] ":signed_contract_in_place1459057835607" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [33] :references_received1459057869650 paramno=-1 name=[33] ":references_received1459057869650" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [45] :payroll_information_given_to_ho1459057881692 paramno=-1 name=[45] ":payroll_information_given_to_ho1459057881692" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [26] :leaving_date1459057889857 paramno=-1 name=[26] ":leaving_date1459057889857" is_param=1 param_type=2 Key: Name: [3] :id paramno=-1 name=[3] ":id" is_param=1 param_type=2
```

How come this code isn't working? The staff_fields contains the fields and that is used in the form as well so I don't get why this isn't working.

I tried enabling the log in IIS through the `my.ini` but that didn't log anything as far as I could see.

***THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!!!!***
`$stmt->execute()` returns TRUE because I am redirected to `staff.php?updated`!

I also have `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` set so what you have linked does not help. Read the question before acting in haste.

Comment: Why you created columns with such name `first_name1459057776924`?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 columns are created through an admin panel and to reduce the likelihood of name conflicts when the client makes them. It appends the timestamp

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE!!!!
`$stmt->execute()` returns TRUE because I am redirected to `staff.php?updated`!

I also have `$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );` set so what you have linked does not help. Read the question before acting in haste.

Comment: @YourCommonSense go tell that to everyone who comes here asking for help. If I have tried to debug it and couldn't figure it out so I came here for some help what is wrong with that? Firstly you mark it as a duplicate because you can't be bothered to read a question properly and then you refuse to admit it and unlock the question so someone HELPFUL can help. I guarantee you that when you unlock it someone will be able to help. Also, if it isn't related to PDO just remove the tag genius.

Comment: Unfortunately, this site is not for debugging help either. You are supposed to provide a specific problem you face, not just dump the code and ask what's wrong with it. I am sorry for that but the site rules are quite clear in this regard. In order to make this question on topic you may start from defining the "doesn't work" statement.

Comment: "It doesn't update in the database"

Comment: Then you may start with creating a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: a code that creates a temporary table with sample data, a query that selects and displays current data, an update query, and another select query that displays the data after update.

Answer (score -1):

Can you replace:

```
foreach($result1 as $q){
$query .= $q['name']."=:".$q['name'].", ";
}
```

With

```
foreach($result1 as $q){
$query .= $q['name']."='".$_POST[$q['name']]."', ";
}
```

You used form to submit the values but you have't captured the values posted from the form.

Hopefully this works.

Cheers

Comment: Hm.. There is something called PDO, which I use.

Comment: Yes, i know what PDO is. I saw you did Bindparam below which i missed earlier.  Have you consider using serialize()? for all the parameters of payroll_informa Params.